# MS SQL SERVER - loops using SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below I write the code which works absolutely fine, but it shows the output using PRINT in 'Messages' tab.

I would like to get everything nice and elegant in one column using SELECT, having rows one under the other. Any idea how to convert it?

Explanation:
We have `CountryName`, `Country ID` and the final output is to get in 1 column name of the country plus information about how many letters the name consists of.

```
DECLARE @Zmienna AS INT
DECLARE @MaxIloscKrajow AS INT
DECLARE @Country AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Zmienna = 0
SET @MaxIloscKrajow = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblCountry)

WHILE @Zmienna <= @MaxIloscKrajow

    BEGIN   
        SET @Country = (SELECT CountryName FROM tblCountry WHERE CountryId = @Zmienna)  

        PRINT @Country + ' has ' + CAST(LEN(@Country) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' letters'

        SET @Zmienna = @Zmienna + 1
    END
```

Comment: Why is this built as a loop in the first place?  It looks like procedure code was syntactically converted to SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Just do the concatenation in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT CountryName + ' has ' + CAST(LEN(CountryName) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' letters' 
FROM tblCountry
```

Comment: the point is that in this way it does not look nice, I would like to get it one row below the other as if USING UNION.

Comment: @user3506071 I'm not sure what you mean - the query will return one row for each country.  What output are you getting?

Comment: Adding in `ORDER BY CountryId` might be what they mean?

Answer (score 0):

With just a slight tweak of your code this should work.

Added temp table variable, and push your results into this table for later output.

```
DECLARE @Zmienna AS INT
DECLARE @MaxIloscKrajow AS INT
DECLARE @Country AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Zmienna = 0
SET @MaxIloscKrajow = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblCountry)

DECLARE @O AS TABLE (Country VARCHAR(MAX), Results VARCHAR(MAX)) --- NEW LINE

WHILE @Zmienna <= @MaxIloscKrajow

    BEGIN   
        SET @Country = (SELECT CountryName FROM tblCountry WHERE CountryId = @Zmienna)  

        INSERT INTO @O VALUES(@Country,@Country + ' has ' + CAST(LEN(@Country) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' letters')  -- altered line

        SET @Zmienna = @Zmienna + 1
    END

SELECT * FROM @O ORDER BY Country
```

Comment: I changed the final code slightly, but adding the table variable was the right choice, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your looking for, but this will space fill the columns so they line up.  Adjust the spacing as needed...

Looks a little weird in SSMS, but cut/paste into Text editor and it lines up fine.

```
select LEFT(CountryName + SPACE(35),35) + 
       ' has ' + 
       LEFT(CAST(LEN(CountryName) as varchar(max))+SPACE(3),3) + 
       ' letters'
from tblCountry
order by CountryId
```

Output is:

```
Bulgaria                            has 8   letters
Ukraine                             has 7   letters
Germany                             has 7   letters
Italy                               has 5   letters
France                              has 6   letters
England                             has 7   letters
United States                       has 13  letters
Russia                              has 6   letters
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to you the could would look like this and it is a nice version:

USE HistoricalEvents
GO

DECLARE @Zmienna AS INT
DECLARE @MaxIloscKrajow AS INT
DECLARE @Country AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Zmienna = 1 -- TO START FROM THE FIRST COUNTRY 
SET @MaxIloscKrajow = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblCountry)

DECLARE @O AS TABLE(Results VARCHAR(MAX)) -*-JUST ONE COLUMN I NEED*

WHILE @Zmienna <= @MaxIloscKrajow

```
BEGIN   
    SET @Country = (SELECT CountryName FROM tblCountry WHERE CountryId = @Zmienna)  

    INSERT INTO @O VALUES(@Country + ' has ' + CAST(LEN(@Country) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' letters')

    SET @Zmienna = @Zmienna + 1

END
```

SELECT * FROM @O ORDER BY Results

--Thanks a lot one more time